# How do I get good error reporting for missing tokens in ANTLR 4?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I've written an ANTLR 4 grammar for a C-style programming language and am trying to improve error messages for missing delimiters, such as a missing comma or missing closing parenthesis in a function argument list.

I thought that ANTLR's single token insertion mechanism would accurately detect missing tokens, but instead I often get a "no viable alternative" error. Here is an example:

```
root
  : expr+ EOF
  ;

expr
  : '(' expr ')'
  | '(' ')' '->' expr
  | ID
  ;

ID: [a-zA-Z0-9$_]+;

Whitespace
  : [ \t\r\n\f]+ -> skip
  ;
```

Parsing input `( -> foo` results in:

```
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input '(->'
```

Instead I'd like to see `missing ')'`. What's the recommended way to achieve this?

The only working solution I've found to date is to make all delimiters optional in the grammar and act on their absence in a visitor.
However, this feels like a workaround and has significant drawbacks that I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that you will get almost exactly the error message you want if you remove the `'(' expr ')'` rule:

```
expr
  : '(' ')' '->' expr
  | ID
  ;
```

Error message:

```
line 1:2 missing ')' at '->'
line 1:4 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', ID}
```

I believe you get errors like "mismatched input X, expecting Y" and "missing X" for LL(1) grammars and `no viable alternative` when lookahead is required at the current position or something like that.

So with that in mind, we can try to rewrite your grammar to be LL(1):

```
expr
  : '(' ( expr ')' | ')' '->' expr )
  | ID
  ;
```

Then the error message becomes:

```
line 1:2 mismatched input '->' expecting {'(', ')', ID}
```

That's pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this refactoring doesn't get me close enough to what I want. In my real-world grammar, the ensuing error message contains many more than three expected tokens, and it isn't obvious at all from that message that a `)` is missing. (Another problem that I discovered is that this refactoring is incompatible with ANTLR 4's way of dealing with operator precedence, which seems to require top-level alternatives.)